# How to display OSM relations (in QGIS) from osm2pgsql populated PostGIS DB

Tags: qgis, postgis, openstreetmap, osm2pgsql

I have a PostGIS DB populated with OSM data (osm2pgsql, standart.style). Now I would like to display a hiking trail (http://www.openstreetmap.org/relation/51855). 
It would also be fine, if I just could extract/export the relation as a multiline.

Is that possible?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You will find the route relations in the `planet_osm_line` table, with a negative osm_id field value corresponding to the OSM relation ID.

Once you have loaded the table, you can set a filter on the table with rightclick on the layer entry:

```
"osm_id" = '-51855'
```

to get only the trail you want, and then export the result to the format you want.

If you want a multiline out of it, perform `Vector -> Geometry Tools -> Single part to Multipart`. The only thing that QGIS can not provide (yet) is a single continuos line out of the OSM data.

Comment: What about ways that belong to multiple relations?

Comment: @NateWessel those ways appear doubled for every relation they are part of.

Comment: Can you explain why the relation would be negative? Is there any documentation/explanation for this?